# How to Create an event when selected time (through DatePicker)occurs in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, event-handling, datepicker, alarm

i wanted to make an customized Alarm clock. So i have taken the Datepicker. Now i wanted to play a sound when the selected time through Datepicker occurs.

So can anyone please tell me which classes or API's to use or any direction to make? How should i make my selected time match with the system time to create an event. i know how to play a sound. Rest things is a Big Question mark for me. Any help will be Appreciable.

till now i have wriiten this code which is just showing a datePicker and on tap of button it shows the time selected. :P

Code:-

```
**.h File**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface The420DudeViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleBar;
    IBOutlet UIButton *setAlarmButton;
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *selectTimePicker;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleBar;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *setAlarmButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *selectTimePicker;

-(IBAction)onTapSetAlarm;

@end



**.m file **

@implementation The420DudeViewController

@synthesize titleBar,setAlarmButton,selectTimePicker;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)onTapSetAlarm
{

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];

    NSDate *selectedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    selectedDate = [selectTimePicker date];

    NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:selectedDate];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Time selected" message:theTime delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"YES" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
//  [timeFormat release];
//  [selectedDate release];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [titleBar release];
    [setAlarmButton release];
    [selectTimePicker release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the `UILocalNotification` class - this will allow your alarm to go off even when the app is closed/in the background:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/UILocalNotification_Class.pdf

Just set the `fireDate` of the localNotification to be `[selectTimePicker date]`, and then schedule it.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply... i will check it now and try... and hope if it makes my day... i will be happy enough to accept the answer. :)

Comment: If anyone have any tutorial for similar kind of thing please give me a link... Chao